# Creating multiple points, using Python AddIn?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, point, python-addin

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
class point(object):
    """Implementation for point_addin.tool (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.shape = "NONE"
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    pt = arcpy.Point()
    pt.X = float(x)
    pt.Y = float(y)
    ptGeoms=[arcpy.PointGeometry(pt)]
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeoms, r"C:\test.shp")
```

There is a problem in my code. While i use this add-in in arcgis, it creates a new point on where i click, but the problem is, it deletes last point i created. I can not save my last point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recreating the same feature class each time you use the `Copy Features` tool. As mentioned in the comments, you can use an insert cursor instead to add the feature to an existing feature class.

I'd do something like this:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
sr = mxd.activeDataFrame.spatialReference
pntFc = r"C:\test.shp"

class point(object):
    """Implementation for point_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE"
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        pt = arcpy.Point()
        pt.X = float(x)
        pt.Y = float(y)
        ptGeoms = [arcpy.Geometry ("POINT", pt, sr)]
        if not arcpy.Exists (pntFc):
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeoms, pntFc)
        else:
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor (pntFc, "SHAPE@") as iCurs:
                iCurs.insertRow (ptGeoms)
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView ()
```